# Testing IP based geolocation

Tags: testing, geolocation

We are implementing an IP based geolocation service, and we need to find some IP's from various markets (LA, NY etc) to fully test the service.

Does anybody know of a directory where we could find what IP ranges are used where?

EDIT: We have already implemented the system, it uses a 3rd party DB and a webservice. We just want some IP's from known markets to verify its working properly.

I'm going to see if I can get what I need from the free maxmind database.

Comment: Ooh. forgot maxmind. we use them for the app's that don't need the high level of accuracy from the third party geolocation app that we use.

Comment: Here's one from Madison, WI: 75.100.126.194

Comment: Corollary to my previous comment: why not just collect a few here from people in different places.

Comment: Might not be too useful unless they use a "what is my IP?" type site. Most broadband connections are class C NAT translated behind a broadband gateway. Still using "what is my IP?" will give you the address of the gateway that you're going through so that's a start.

Comment: Actually 75.100.126.194 shows up as a medium connection speed dsl line from tds telecom with fixed, i.e. not mobile, routing. (-:

Comment: @FlySwat, why don't you use HTML5 or Google Geolocation? Why you need to check by IP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if cost is a factor but there are a few open source databases knocking about. [This one](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country) claims 99.3% accuracy on its free version with 99.8% for its paid version. They've also got a [Free & Open Source City Database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) (76% accuracy at city level).

They're both available as CSV-based databases so you can easily take a known location and get an IP range for ISPs in the area.

The tougher part is getting access to a computer in that IP range.

Comment: Not sure why I'm being voted down. You can use the maxmind databases in both directions!

Comment: Me neither, have a +1.  Great suggestion, I might use this for my idea for geolocation.

Comment: He was downvoted because prior to edit, he answered the wrong question :)

Comment: To avoid the "getting access to a computer in that IP range" requirement you can setup an apache http proxy and forward requests from your external interface to your local interface, via a interface configured with the IP address you need to simulate.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking for sites providing lists of anonymizers. They usually list the countries for the anonymizer sites. Then either use the IP provided or do a lookup on the anonymizer name.

Also try searching for lists of anonymous proxies.

We trawled the logs for our huge web site and built up a test collection.

Sorry I can't pass it on. )-:

cheers,

Rob

Answer (score 3):

maybe this database will be useful for you:
http://www.hostip.info/dl/index.html
it's a collection of ip adresses with countries and cities.

Answer (score 1):

Many open source projects have worldwide mirrors; you can find a country-indexed list of [Debian mirrors](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list) and [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/mirrors/) mirrors. (Note that kernel.org specifically has many mirrors per country; there are eleven [United States mirrors](http://kernel.org/mirrors/countries/html/US.html), which are located in different regions of the country and would give different information.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an automation tool, such as AutoIT, to fire off a series of IP addresses at a whois database service such as [arin](http://ws.arin.net/whois) or RIPE, and harvest the addressed responses, probably just varying the first two parts of the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) with a [strict exit node](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/01/29/configure-tor-to-use-a-specific-country-as-an-exit-node/).

You'll need to use these options in your config:

```
ExitNodes server1, server2, server3
StrictExitNodes 1
```

You'll also need to identify exit nodes that work for you in the region that you want.  I suggest using the Search Whois feature at [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/) to see it's location if the Tor country icon isn't good enough.  It can be a bit of a pain to identify working Tor nodes in each region that you wish to test, but it's possible and free.